# Could not load File or Assembly CrystalDecisions

Tags: crystal-reports

Anybody knows how to get rid of the image error attached i can't find a reference to the missing assembly within the solution itself nor the file preview.aspx
Mind you i am using VS2015 Pro with update 3. the version of CR on my local machine is 13 
Any direction is greatly appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 0):

who ever wanted to know the answer the question above, follow the directions below to get rid of this error,
GO to 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETClientFiles\crystalreportviewers13
and edit the preview.aspx file and change the verzion to match your machine verzion. make sure you open the file as an administrator to prevent read only mode.